# Refreshing DIV using ajax when XML data is updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I've spent the last 4 years trying to solve this problem (on and off) and quite frankly my brain hurts.

I'm a voluntary designer for a local community project (a radio station). We have an "On Air" module that displays what track is currently playing and coming up.

Until recently I was using auto refreshing iframes that contained HTML files with the track information (these HTML files are automatically uploaded via FTP every 15 seconds by our playout system). These iframes refreshed every 15 seconds, however, this often lead to 404's in the iframe and ugly flickering as they reloaded.

I've spent some time looking in to an AJAX solution. I currently have an XML file with the track information (which the playout system automatically uploads via FTP every 15 seconds) and a HTML document that uses AJAX to refresh every 10 seconds. However, while I've helped fix the 404 issue, I'm still left with the ugly flicker as the text refreshes.

I have read that there is a way to have ajax refresh only if values in a database have changed, but I haven't had much luck in researching ways to do this if an XML document is updated.

If anyone can help point me in the right direction, many cookies and love will be bestowed upon you. Thanks!

Here's the code I currently have:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
(function($)
{
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $.ajaxSetup(
        {
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#content').hide();
                $('#loading').show();
            },
            complete: function() {
                $('#loading').hide();
                $('#content').show();
            },
            success: function() {
                $('#loading').hide();
                $('#content').show();
            }
        });
        var $container = $("#content");
        $container.load("test.xml");
        var refreshId = setInterval(function()
        {
            $container.load('test.xml');
        }, 10000);
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content"></div>
    <img src="loading.gif" id="loading" alt="loading" style="display:none;" />
</div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the test.xml:

```html
<OnAirInfo>
 <CurrentTrack><OCP_NOW_ITEMNAME></CurrentTrack>
 <CurrentArtist><OCP_NOW_ARTIST1NAME></CurrentArtist>
 <NextTrack><OCP_NEXT_ITEMNAME></NextTrack>
 <NextArtist><OCP_NEXT_ARTIST1NAME></NextArtist>
</OnAirInfo>
```

Comment: Why don't you add code in the question

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5's `Server-Sent Events`

A `server-sent event` is when a web page automatically gets updates from a server.

All you have to do is create an `EventSource object` and pass it the URL of your server file(Here I am assuming `.php` file).

```
var source = new EventSource('your_file.php'); //This file will fetch the updates from `database`.
```

Then you can listen to the events for the updates.

```
source.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
  console.log(e.data);
}, false);
```

There is a very nice explanation on [HTML5rocks- EventSource](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/) about this concept. You should definitely take a look into it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Okay..dont forget to accept the answer if this solves your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

By default, any AJAX call is cached by the browser itself and won't transfert the whole file if the server say it hasn't changed.

For you case, I would suggest the folowing :

```
<div id="content">
    <p id="CurrentTrack"></p><br/>
    <p id="CurrentArtist"></p><br/>
    <p id="NextTrack"></p><br/>
    <p id="NextArtist"></p>
</div>
<script>
    setInterval(function()
    {
    $.get("/url/to/your/xml/",
    function(data){
        // In case your server don't serve the file with the right mime type
        var response = $($.parseXML(data)).find("OnAirInfo"); 
        // Data extraction from xml
        var CurrentTrack = response.children("CurrentTrack").text();
        var CurrentArtist = response.children("CurrentArtist").text();
        var NextTrack = response.children("NextTrack").text();
        var NextArtist = response.children("NextArtist").text();

        // Smooth text transition to prevent the "flickering"
        $("#CurrentTrack").fadeOut(function() {
            $(this).text(CurrentTrack).fadeIn();
        });
        $("#CurrentArtist").fadeOut(function() {
            $(this).text(CurrentArtist).fadeIn();
        });
        $("#NextTrack").fadeOut(function() {
            $(this).text(NextTrack).fadeIn();
        });
        $("#NextArtist").fadeOut(function() {
            $(this).text(NextArtist).fadeIn();
        });
    });
    }, 10000);
</script>
```

The smooth transition with the fadeout/fadein should look better than the text changing directly.

off course you have to adapt it to your system but this loading way will :

- Prevent any 404 to interfear (the ajax success will just not be called so the text will stay the same until the next update
- Allow for a wide range of data to be transmited (you could add the album cover thumbnail as a base64 string in your xml, or the url to the picture)
- Allow you to keep the formating on the page and not on a separate one

**Edit : Updated to your code specification**